# Generating static pages (3/4)BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to build my app but when I run it on my pc everything is fine. what is the issue? I1m using nextjs 13 so the apis are in the page directory and others in app directory.

```
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export async function findIsomoById(itemId: string) {
  try {
    // Connect to the MongoDB database
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("amasomo_ya_misa");
    const collection = db.collection("amasomo");

    console.log(new ObjectId(itemId));
    //from terminal:  new ObjectId("63e2b8ee59f3dd8e0ada240b")

    // Find the item in the collection by its _id
    const isomo = await collection.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(itemId) });

    return isomo;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error("An error occurred while finding the item.");
  } finally {
    //ServerClosedEvent.apply;
  }
}
```

The error I`m getting

```
[=   ] info  - Generating static pages (3/4)BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
    at new BSONTypeError (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
    at new ObjectId (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
    at findIsomoById (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:553:21)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AmasomoReview (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:573:19)
Error: An error occurred while finding the item.
    at findIsomoById (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:561:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AmasomoReview (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:573:19)

Error occurred prerendering page "/isomo/[id]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: An error occurred while finding the item.
    at findIsomoById (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:561:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AmasomoReview (C:\Users\InezaGuy\reactpr\amasomo_yamisa\.next\server\app\isomo\[id]\page.js:573:19)
info  - Generating static pages (4/4)
```

Comment: What values you supplied to the string `itemId`?

Comment: the values are a string of 24 characters and they are generated by mongoDB when I`m inserting Data

Comment: Note the requirement in the error log: `24 hex characters`. Not any 24 characters. This is also specified in [official MongoDB ObjectId doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#description)

Comment: The characters are generated by mongoDB and it is work fine when I run npm run dev but with npm run build I get an error

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide some sample input of the string?

Comment: I added the  result from the terminal for console